# Unrecognized selector sent to instance while archiving nested custom object

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to save the custom object that includes another custom object to `UserDefault` but I keep getting

> 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'

error.
I have implemented the `NSCoding` protocol to both the classes.

```
let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: details)
```

I am trying to archive RideDetails Class and save it to `UserDefault`.
I have done similar in another project which didn't include nested custom object and it worked fine. May be because of the nested object it didn't work. I couldn't figure it out.

**DriverProfile Class**

```
class DriverProfile: NSObject, NSCoding{
private var userId: Int
private var driverId:Int
private var firstName: String
private var lastName: String
private var phone: String
private var email:String?
private var location: CLLocation?
private var vehicleType: String
private var vehicleNo: String
private var rating:Double?
private var imageName:String?


init(userId: Int, driverId: Int, firstName:String, lastName: String, phone:String, email:String?, location:CLLocation?,vehicleType:String,vehicleNo:String,rating:Double?,imageName:String?) {
        self.userId = userId
        self.driverId = driverId
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.phone = phone
        self.email = email
        self.location = location
        self.vehicleType = vehicleType
        self.vehicleNo = vehicleNo
        self.rating = rating
        self.imageName = imageName
    }

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(userId, forKey:"userId")
    aCoder.encode(driverId, forKey:"driverId")
    aCoder.encode(firstName, forKey:"firstName")
    aCoder.encode(lastName, forKey:"lastName")
    aCoder.encode(phone, forKey:"phone")
    aCoder.encode(email, forKey:"email")
    aCoder.encode(location, forKey:"location")
    aCoder.encode(vehicleType, forKey:"vehicleType")
    aCoder.encode(vehicleNo, forKey:"vehicleNo")
    aCoder.encode(rating, forKey:"rating")
    aCoder.encode(imageName, forKey:"imageName")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    userId = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "userId")
    driverId = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "driverId")
    firstName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "firstName") as! String
    lastName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "lastName") as! String
    phone = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "phone") as! String
    email = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "email") as? String
    location = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "location") as? CLLocation
    vehicleType = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "vehicleType") as! String
    vehicleNo = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "vehicleNo") as! String
    rating = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "rating") as? Double
    imageName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "imageName") as? String
    super.init()
}
```

}

**RideDetails Class**

```
class RideDetails: NSObject{
private var rideTime:String?
private var rideId:Int
private var driverProfile:DriverProfile
private var destinationLocation: CLLocation?
private var myLocation:CLLocation?
private var otpCode:String
private var trackRideURL:String
private var customerId:Int
private var extendedRange:Bool?
private var extendedRangePrice:Double?


init(rideTime:String?,rideId:Int,driverProfile:DriverProfile,destinationLocation:CLLocation?,myLocation:CLLocation?,otpCode:String,trackRideURL:String,customerId:Int,extendedRange:Bool?,extendedRangePrice:Double?) {
    self.rideTime = rideTime
    self.rideId = rideId
    self.driverProfile = driverProfile
    self.destinationLocation = destinationLocation
    self.myLocation = myLocation
    self.otpCode = otpCode
    self.trackRideURL = trackRideURL
    self.customerId = customerId
    self.extendedRange = extendedRange
    self.extendedRangePrice = extendedRangePrice
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(rideTime, forKey:"rideTime")
    aCoder.encode(rideId, forKey:"rideId")
    aCoder.encode(driverProfile, forKey:"driverProfile")
    aCoder.encode(destinationLocation, forKey:"destinationLocation")
    aCoder.encode(myLocation, forKey:"myLocation")
    aCoder.encode(otpCode, forKey:"otpCode")
    aCoder.encode(trackRideURL, forKey:"trackRideURL")
    aCoder.encode(customerId, forKey:"customerId")
    aCoder.encode(extendedRange, forKey:"extendedRange")
    aCoder.encode(extendedRangePrice, forKey:"extendedRangePrice")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    rideTime = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "rideTime") as? String
    rideId = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "rideId")
    driverProfile = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "driverProfile") as! DriverProfile
    destinationLocation = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "destinationLocation") as? CLLocation
    myLocation = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "myLocation") as? CLLocation
    otpCode = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "otpCode") as! String
    trackRideURL = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "trackRideURL") as! String
    customerId = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "customerId")
    extendedRange = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "extendedRange") as? Bool
    extendedRangePrice = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "extendedRangePrice") as? Double
    super.init()
}


}
```

Comment: ridedetail class need to confirm to NSCoding ?

Comment: lol.. that was so stupid of me .. thank you so much